# Redis Pub/Sub Scaling

Tags: node.js, redis

I've been rewriting my `nodejs` game app to read memory from `redis` so I could ultimately scale it if it were to ever grow large. But, I stopped because I feel like I am going about it the wrong way.  For example:

[image]

`Server 1` is on port 9300

`Server 2` is on port 9301

Now, let's say a player from the `Server 1` wants to send a `private message` to a player that is on `Server 2`.

#### What I currently do

`Server 2` will send a publish signal to redis, and `Server 1` will catch that signal as well, and if that user is on that server, it will send them a notification along with the message.

#### Some questions

1) *Wouldn't it be more appropiate to just have `Server 2` send a message to `Server 1` without publishing to `redis`?*

2) `Server 2` doesn't keep a track of all the connected clients that `Server 1` has, so it wouldn't be possible. Unless, I keep track of all connected clients on every server aswell? That would require the client to connect to multiple servers on each visit.

3) Let's say I have 10 servers. A user on `Server 5` wants to send a private message to a user on `Server 1`. If I send a pub signal through `redis`, `Servers 4,6,7,8,9,2,3` will all receive that signal as well... which is unneeded? Is that when Peer to Peer connections come into play? Or is that the extra bandwidth that is required for scaling and I'm overthinking everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could change concept of your app by adding RabbitMQ instead of redis pub/sub. RMQ would allow smarter message routing.

Basicly each user can listen its own messages:

- User connects to server (1-x)
- Server subscribes to RMQ exchange messages with user routing key
- When user publishes private message it's sent to provided exchange with specific user routing key

Still that concept will hit the limit if you get large number of users. Connection count to RMQ server will grow intensivly. In that case you can scale RMQ or change connection concept:

- Save all user connection info to redis
- When user sends private message to some other user first find on which server instance user is
- Send message only to specific server instance (fetched from user connection information)

Comment: `Send message only to specific server instance (fetched from user connection information)`. I like this the concept, but even if I store the users connection in redis, that particular nodejs server cannot send data to that user because that person they are private messaging (session object) is only available on the server they are on. Or am I missing something? :)

Comment: If you have "user1" connected to "server1" and "user2" connected to "server2": 
 - "user1" sends message to "server1"
 - "server1" find info about "user2" (he gets "server2")
 - "server1" forwards message to "server2"
Communication in last step can be achieved by RMQ or specific instance of redis sub (each server has its own sub)

Comment: `each server has its own sub`, awww. That way, not every single server will get notified if there are 20 servers, and the user from server 1 sends to server 10.  (If I do store where that user is connected in redis). I think I got it now. Thank you Bernard.

Comment: @Bernard what if we need to add more servers on the fly for horizontal scaling would the current instances need to be stopped so that those instances are aware of the new server? that way there will be a down time

Comment: @ShershaFn sry, I've missed your comment. It's pretty old question but I could say that solution should scale horizontally (adding servers) with some kind of redis/RMQ combination which is described in answer. Redis supports cluster these days and it can scale pretty well. RMQ might become bottleneck on larger deployments but that also can be resolved (don't over-engineer it too soon :) )